# Performance testing on Messaging queue

Tags: performance, performance-testing

I have secnario to test , when I send rest API using loadrunner / jmeter parllely request using consuming by the Messaging queue .so I need to check difference of how may messages are received by message queue  per second and how much time it's taking to acknowledge the message . Is there any way that we can check this ? Which is better way to report this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. > I need to check difference of how may messages are received by message queue per second

   put JMS Publisher and [JMS Subscriber](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher) into different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Subscriber), this way you will be able to measure throughput (the number of messages per second) which you're sending/receiving
2. If you want to track each message and record its processing time

   - in 1st Thread Group extract [message ID](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-message-service/9780596802264/re03.html) and store it into JMeter Properties along with current timestamp in [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) like:

     ```
     props.put(messageID, System.currentTimeMillis())
     ```
   - in the 2nd Thread Group extract message ID and look for its submit time, then subtract it from the current time, this way you will get message processing time

     ```
     def entry = props.entrySet().find { entry -> entry.getKey().equals(messageID) }
     def now = System.currentTimeMillis()
     def sent = entry.getValue()
     def processingTime = sent - now
     vars.put('processingTime', processingTime as String)
     ```

   you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=processingTime
   ```

   so the value for each and every message will be stored into .jtl results file and you will be able to plot it at the HTML Reporting Dashboard

References:

- [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)
- [Generating customs graphs over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)